# Using a tree structure in Symfony2 (doctrine2): how to set the order?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, twig

In my Symfony2 app I have four entities that together make a nav menu:

{ Category, Level1Item, Level2Item, Level3Item }

Through "parent" en "children" properties they are connected and a hierarchy is formed.
In the MySql-db, the tables have a field called parent_id (except for the Categories as they are on the root level).
In addition, there is a property "order" (mapped to the db-field "order_id").

I feed the categories via the entity manager to a Twig template.
The template iterates over the items in level1, 2 and 3 if existent.

The order in which all items are displayed is in line with the item id's.
However, I would like to make the order-property leading.

In most cases, the order would come down do: { parent_id, order_id }.
Because the child-items for each parent could have the order 1, 2, 3, the order_id's itself are not unique. They are though within each parent-pool, no two children with order_id 2 for parent_id 1 for example.

I know how to force the order using sorting-functionality when using the QueryBuilder, or when using a custom function in an entityRepository. But how to set a default result order for the ->findAll() method that Twig will work with, drilling down to the children...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify order in entity mapping annotation like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Category", mappedBy="parent")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"name" = "ASC"})
 */
private $children;
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas! I tried this before, but then I did it the wrong way. I understand now, that you only enter the properties of the children to order by. I was thinking of sql-tables, thinking of ordering by { parent, order }, but that indeed makes no sense as you are already on a parent level... :)